# Too many connections using Hibernate and mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3 and mysql sever 5.5 for myweb application with spring 3.0

I am getting exception as Too many connections......

My java file where I create session is as follows:

```
public class DBConnection {

    static{

    }

    public Session getSession(){

         Session session = null;
         SessionFactory sessionFactory= null;
         sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        return session;

    }

}
```

and I call this method where I need session

as

```
Session session=new DBConnection().getSession();
```

and after

```
transaction.commit();
```

I close session by using

```
session.close();
```

please help me in solving problem.......

my hibernate.cfg.xml is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">lax</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">100</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name=""></property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Before calling `session.Close()` call `session.Flush`. It seems your connections aren't being returned to the pool after use.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because you are using a connection pool which got created as soon as you build SessionFactory, but the connections are acquired only when you open a Session. Now, you are closing the session, due to which connections are released, but are not closed and are held up by the pool. Now, you are again creating a SessionFactory, hence creating a new pool, then getting a session, hence creating a new connection and so on.. which will eventually reach the maximum number of connections allowed.

What you have to do is using one Connection Pool (using one SessionFactory) and getting and releasing the connections from the same pool.

```
public class DBConnection {

      private static SessionFactory factory;
      static {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }

      public Session getSession() {
            return factory.openSession();
      }

      public void doWork() {
           Session session = getSession();
           // do work.
           session.close();
      }

     // Call this during shutdown
     public static void close() {
          factory.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: Need an advice. What about when it goes to servlets? They are multi threaded, so will this way affect it?

Answer (score 5):

You create new `SessionFactory`s every time you need a `Session` and don't close them.

Usually you need to create session factory only once during startup of your application, and close it during shutdown. For example, as follows:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    static {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return factory.openSession();
    }

    // Call this during shutdown
    public static void close() {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Also take a look at [contextual sessions pattern](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session).

Comment: @LaxmikantKumbhare: When you shut down the whole application, e.g. in `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used

```
Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(this.sessionFactory,
                true);
```

to get session. Above the DAO layer, transaction with annotations (@Transactional) is used in add, edit or delete. Our application uses shiro for authentication and authorization. In each page access, it creates at least 5 connections. So the subsequent request keeps on increasing mysql connection. Thanks to @Venu I found out that

```
show variables like "max_connections";
```

shows default maximum connection available. Initially (I guess) it was set to 151. This number would soon exhaust because another variable "innodb_open_files" was set to 300. By intuition I can say if one table reaches maximum connection of 300 it would only go for clean up (just like garbage collection in java).

One would think, if we would increase the value of "max_connections" to 300 it solve this error, but as I said earlier "innodb_open_files" does not go for cleanup until one table reaches that limit. In our case user table which would be called frequently would reach  that limit for cleanup to happen. This means, you cannot know before hand what is the perfect number for "max_connections".

In mysql configuration file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" max_connections is set as

```
max_connections        = 1000
```

I did not change

value of "innodb_open_files", which is default to "300"

```
mysql> show variables like "innodb_open_files";
```

During execution of your program you can use

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

to find out how many connections are open. I guess all the processes in Sleep state can be deleted in next cycle of cleanup (but its only my guess).

To simulate more than 1000 users, executing some url in your web project, you can use software like jmeter and set number of thread (users) to 1000. Use of more user also depends upon available RAM in your computer. I was able to simulate more than 3000 connections sending requests at 1 second interval. A good and sufficient tutorial on how to do this is listed on [roseindia](http://www.roseindia.net/jmeter/)

Now my query. I have not closed session on any place. I guess @Transaction was created for that purpose (mysql proves that, because all those connections get cleaned once the limit reaches). Due to merge problem of detached objects, I had to used OpenSessionInViewFilter. OpenSessionInViewFilter (can be OpenSessionInViewInterceptor) opens the session a little longer for the merge to happen, which might be the reason so many connections remain open in mysql (Don't know clearly). Since it works for so many users it seems a good solution, but is there a better solution to make it work under default max connection size of mysql. i.e 151 connections.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issues with Hibernate mysql conenctions
The following two things helped fix my connection problems

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class DBConnection {
private static SessionFactory factory;
static public Session getSession() {
    if (factory == null) {
        System.out.println("--------New connection----");

        factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }
    //System.out.println("--------old connection----");

    return factory.openSession();
}


    // Call this during shutdown
    public static void close() {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

*Create a singleton class for getting a DBConnection*

*Do not forget to perform **session.close()** when your query is complete*

Also in "hibernate.cfg.xml"
add this line

`<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    ....
    <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>
    ....
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>`

under

Answer (score -2):

> ### JAVA ISSUE
>
> #### Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10785770/598424

**MYSQL ISSUE**

YOU NEED TO LOGIN AS SUPERUSER. THEN EXECUTE THIS CODE:

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_CONNECTIONS = 200;
```

HOWEVER, THIS ONLY LASTS UNTIL THE MYSQL SERVER RESTARTS. IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE IT PERMANENTLY, YOU CAN ADD THE FOLLOWING LIKE UNDER MYSQLD SECTION.

```
MAX_CONNECTIONS = 500
```

OR

IF YOU HAVE TOO MANY PROCESSES LINGERING AROUND ON THE DATABASE SERVER, THEN YOU MAY REACH A LIMIT AND NO NEW ONES WILL BE ALLOWED TO BE STARTED.

To see if this is the case, take a look at your processes from the MySQL Monitor prompt by typing:

```
show processlist;
```

Then you will see the lingering processes. Each has an ID, and you can kill them by process ID right in the MySQL Monitor by typing:

```
 kill 2309344;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but do u know any solution from java side?

Comment: this is not an issue with java. Its an issue with mysql.

Comment: It is a Java issue, the SessionFactory is recreated anew every time. Love Hasija's answer explains it all.

Comment: This is not a recommended answer at all.